# Report Exception when choose Chart Line with Markers

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

i choose chart Line with Markers or smooth Line with Markers  after that immediatly when i add Values it throw exception

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in Microsoft.ReportingServices.Designer.Controls.dll

Additional information: .75pt is not a valid unit designator. Valid unit designators are in, mm, cm, pt, pc.

[image exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTvTB.png)

[Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsSpW.png)

in contrast when i choose other type of chart it works fine

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with regional settings on your system vs report builder, try change decimal separator to ',' and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After some attempts, I find out, that this problem appears only for line charts with markers. I changed a chart type to a line chart without marker and the problem was solved.

Together with my colleagues, we agreed that Report Builder is an act of revenge from MS.